Is the highlighted part false?

The highlighted part seems to suggest that if $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ is a basis of $V$, then there has to be $\dim\text{Null } T$ many vectors from that basis that are mapped to $0$ and $\dim\text{Range }T$ many vectors that are not mapped to 0.
I have the following counter example.
Let $T: \mathbf{R^2} \to \mathbf{R^2}$ a linear transformation with the standard bases for each space.
Then let $$T \left( \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \right) 
= T \left( \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} \right) = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} $$
Then $\text{Range }T = \{ \begin{bmatrix} a \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \mid a \in \mathbf{R} \}$
hence by the rank-nullity theorem we have $\dim \text{Null }T = 1$ but none of the basis vectors are mapped to zero. Hence their claim is false.
Is there anything that can be done to fix this proof?
I don't think so since everything else in that argument follows from the highlighted part.
Thanks.

@Malady But the exercise requires you to show that there is such a matrix for any basis of $V$, so I think it needs to true for any basis of $V$.

Yes, this is false. The correct statement is that there is at most $s$ basis vectors which map to $0$, and at least $r$ basis vectors such that their image under $T$ is nonzero and, therefore, has a nontrivial decomposition in the basis $w_1,\dots,w_m$.

It is false and sloppily formulated.
Actually $s$ does not play any role in the proof. All we have to know is that there are at least $r$ basis vectors $v_i$ such that $T(v_i) \ne 0$.
Let us first prove it. Assume that less than $r$ of the $v_i$ have non-zero images under $T$. Since $\operatorname{range} T$ is spanned by the $T(v_i)$, $i = 1,\ldots, n$, $\operatorname{range} T$ would be spanned by less than $r$ elements, thus $\dim \operatorname{range} T < r$, a contradiction.
Now let $i_1, \ldots, i_r \in \{1,\ldots,n\}$ be indices such that $T(v_{i_k}) \ne 0$. Thus, if $T(v_{i_k}) = \sum_{j = 1}^m a_{ji_k}w_j$, then at least one of the $a_{ji_k}$ is non-zero. This shows that at least $r$ entries of the matrix $(a_{ij})$ of $T$ with respect to the given bases are non-zero.

The statement of the theorem says $M$ must have several $0$ entries.
I think if you edit the highlighted sentence to change "... are $s$ vectors ..." to  "... are at most $s$ vectors ..." then the proof will be correct.
